# Dividing integer polynomial by an integer in point value representation

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic

Let $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be represented in point-value representation. Is there a method to divide $p(x)$ by an integer, say $a$, without converting back to coefficient representation. What if $a$ does not divide every coefficient in $p(x)$, is it possible to obtain the quotient of the division?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious, if $q(x) = p(x) / a$, then for any point $r$, $q(r) = p(r) / a$.

---

Based on the comments, the actual question is more like

> I know how to represent sufficiently small integers in terms of integers modulo $N$; what about rational numbers?

[Rational reconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_reconstruction_(mathematics)) is a thing you can do — and there are variations to get more precision all the rational numbers share a common denominator.

(note that if $N$ is not relatively prime to the denominator, if you still *really* wanted to do this you'd have to use some sort of $p$-adic floating point notation for each offending prime)

However, you're likely much better off representing a rational polynomial in some numerator-denominator form — that is, as an integer polynomial (represented in your favorite manner) for the numerator and an integer (represented in your favorite manner) for the denominator.

In any case, you need to be careful with the available precision; exact arithmetic with rational numbers tends to consume precision rapidly unless you're careful about what calculations you're doing.

---

Note that there is no hope of doing *approximate* division in this manner; e.g. rounding coefficients to the nearest integer. Your only options in that case are:

- Convert back to coefficient form
- Use a representation where values are floating point complex numbers rather than modular integers.

Some mixed floating-point and modular integer representation might be possible, but if so it would be very complicated to get right.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/793204)

Comment: @mlc: To the contrary, it states exactly to compute the point-value representation of the quotient from the point-value representation of the numerator.

Comment: I should have stated the problem I am facing specifically instead of generalizing it. My problem is as follows: I compute the NTT of $p(x)$ over some prime, say $n$. Dividing by $a$ is equivalent to multiplying $a^{-1} \pmod{n}$ by each point. When I compute the INTT of the product, I should expect $q(x)$. This algorithm works as long as $a$ divides each coefficient in $p(x)$. How to generalize it to count for all cases?

Comment: @caesar: You do the same thing; so your question is really not about doing division, but how to represent rational numbers.

Comment: @Hurkyl: That was exactly what I need. Thank you!